# Gridding in a Nested Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, color

We have a nested matrix as:

```
nested={{he, {{e, f, g, h}, {s, 0, q, i}, {s, 0, q, j}}}, {ho, {{e, f, g, 
  h}, {0, u, t, i}, {u, t, 0, j}}}}
```

and with the line `MapAt[MatrixForm, nested, {{All, All}, {}}]` the matrix form can be shown:

[image]

The desire situation can be achieved when some elements such as "he" and "ho" written in the background of Blue (color) and in the right sub_matrices, the elements in the top rows ("e, f, g, h") and the most right columns ("h,i,j") can be written in the background of Darker[ Yellow, 0.01].
However I know `Grid` can help for matrices or tables but I don't know how I can access to the desire situation for a nested matrix with help of Grid or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mfnested = MapAt[MatrixForm, nested, {{}, {;; , ;;}}];
colF = MapAt[Function[{i}, Item[i, Background -> #2[[1]]]], #, #2[[2]]] &;

Fold[colF, mfnested, 
  {{Yellow, {{1, All, 2, 1, 1, All}, {1, All, 2, 1, All, -1}}}, 
   {Lighter@Blue, {{All, All, 1}}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[MapAt[Grid[#, Background -> {{-1 -> Yellow}, {1 -> Yellow}}] &, 
           nested, {{All, 2}}], Background -> {{Lighter@Blue}, None}, 
     Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

`MapIndexed` can be used to apply styling to elements conditionally based upon the their indices within the matrix.  For example:

```
format[v_, {_, 1}] := framed[v, White, Blue]
format[v_, {_, 2}] := MatrixForm[v, TableSpacing -> {None, None}]
format[v_, {_, 2, 1, _} | {_, 2, _, 4}] := framed[v, Black, Darker[Yellow, 0.01]]
format[v_, _] := v

framed[v_, f_, b_] := Framed[Style[v, f], Background -> b, FrameStyle -> None]

MapIndexed[format, nested, -1] // MatrixForm
```

[image: screenshot showing formatted matrix]

The helper function `format` defines the rules for each element of the matrix based upon its index.  For example, the index pattern `{_, 1}` matches the elements in the first column of the main matrix, and the index pattern `{_, 2, _, 4}` matches the fourth column of the each submatrix in the second column of the main matrix.

The helper function `framed` provides a shorthand for a frame with no border and specified foreground and background colours.

Finally, the `MapIndexed` expression is used to apply `format` to every element at all levels in the matrix (down to level bottom-most level, `-1`).